# Magento 2 Reports are not accurate

Tags: magento2

The report generated by Magento 2 (backend > reports > sales > coupons) does not show exact values.
For eg the following order was placed with discount -10CHF
[image: order totals from backend]

However, on the coupon report on the same store scope does not show the same
[image]

*All the totals are tax inclusive including the shipping cost.

**The issue is similar with other reports, for eg the order report also has incorrect totals.**
[image]

Do you guys have experienced this issue ? Any help would be appreciated.